# Error in raster displays of NoData cells when "zoomed in" past scale 1:3,000,000?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, scale, display

I have encountered an error in how ArcGIS Desktop displays a Raster file (.TIF format) at different scales. At scales greater than 1:3,76,600, when I'm zoomed in, the raster displays mostly correctly, showing only a border of low-value cells, or no border -the "border" appears inconsistently. (first picture)

[image]

What is consistent is that when I zoom out, specifically when I go from 1: 3,000,000 to 1:4,000,000, the white background (correctly indicating no-data cells) change to blue (indicating the lowest value "bin" in the classification). When I check the cell values, the cells are NoData value, even when zoomed in and blue (and they should be clear).  (second picture)

[image]

Any suggestions?

I want to display this data zoomed out to a scale smaller than 1:3,000,000 but it is falsely visualizing the data. I am working in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 with all licenses installed. In Layer Properties > General Tab > "Scale Range," "Show layer at all scales" is checked.

Comment: Can you specify upon the raster dataset: Is it a 1 channel 8bit raster, or are you displaying a RGB image? How do you assign the yellow and the blue colors?

Comment: 1 band, 64bit pixel depth. It is an enormous raster, 1665 columns and 2480 rows. Looking again it does say NoData Value = -1.7e+308, instead of either of the "more" correct options of 0 or NoData.

Comment: You can re-assign the NoData manually if you don't like -1.7e308. Do this in _ArcCatalog_: Browse to your raster and open its _Properties_ from the context menu; There is an _edit button_ next to the _"NoData"_ field, change NoData to any unused value (e.g. 0?). I assume the 64bit data type is intentional - if not, I highly recommend to re-calculate your raster. If you are dealing with integers, you should also move away from floating point to an integer data type: Although any data type and any NoData value will work, the discussed pyramid issue is more likely with a floating point raster.

Comment: by the way, your NoData value is _-1.7e+308_ because this is the max double (negative) number of 64bit floating point encoding. [Wikipedia has some examples about that.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sometimes encounter similar errors, especially if the raster values repesent some non-continuous data (like classifications). This is **probably related to pyramids** which seem to [not fully respect nodata values](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000boJO&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=Imagery) in some cases.

There are two possible workarounds:

- [**Rebuild the pyramids**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m1000000) of your raster data. For classification rasters, you should use *Nearest Neighbor* technique (interpolating makes no sense there). You can also clear the pyramids (i.e. set pyramid level to 0) if re-building pyramids has no effect. The raster is then displayed without pyramids - this may slow down its display depending on your raster size. For small rasters, you may well go without pyramids. (I tend to turn off pyramids for classification rasters)
- [Manually assign a display color of your NoData value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000089000000) for each raster image.

Comment: lavarider, thanks for your comments and answers.  I will attempt to both rebuild pyramids as well as set the pyramid level to 0. For now, though, I would note that I have manually assigned NoData to be transparent....this makes me think you are right about the lack of pyramid respect.

Comment: Hmmm. When I tried rebuilding the pyramids using the Geoprocessing> Environments > Raster Storage settings, nothing changes.

Comment: ah-ha! instead of working only in the Geoprocessing menu options, I used the Build Pyramids tool (Tools> Data Management) and set the Pyramid Levels = 0, as @lavarider suggested through the suggested links in their answer. It appears the raster is now correctly showing NoData cells with no color.